# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{ \infty} a_n(z-6)^n .$

Tags: complex-analysis

if $f(z) =\frac{\log (1+ z) }{ z }= \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty} a_n(z-6)^n $. then radius of convergence is ______ ?

I thinks radius of convergence is $1$   because  $\log (1+z)$ is analytic for $|z| < 1$ and not analytic at $z = −1$. So, the radius
of convergence is $R$ = $1$

Is its  true  or false ?

Comment: Note that you need to give the radius of convergence around z=6

Comment: @GSofer i thinks it  will be both same $z=0$ and $z=6$

Comment: The function $\ln(1+z)/z$ is continuous on $(0,12)$, with a pole at $0$. With elementary functions like this one, that means a power series centered at $6$ has radius $6$.

Comment: @alex.jordan There is no pole at $0.$

Comment: @santosh No, the radius of convergence centered at $6$ is greater than $1.$

Comment: @zhw Thanks, I missed that. So that shortcut logic doesn't apply. Glad I only posted it as a comment, not an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\log (1+z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,-1].$ The function $\dfrac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$ Thus at first glance, it appears as if $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C \setminus ((-\infty,-1]\cup \{0\}).$ But note that the singularity of $f$ at $0$ is removable. Thus, with the center of our power series at $6,$ $f$ extends to be holomorphic on $D(6,7).$ Thus the radius of convergence of the power series of $f$ centered at $6$ is at least $7.$ Now argue that this radius is exactly $7.$

Comment: thanks u.. @zwh

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$
f(z)=\left(\ln 7+\ln\left(1+\frac{z-6}7\right)\right)\cdot\frac16\left(1+\frac{z-6}6\right)^{-1}
$$